# Query to sum sales totals for X number of months given dates

Tags: sql, date, ms-access

I would like to make a query that SUMS the total number of sales of each product ID for a group of months (ie. May - August)

I want:

```html
+------------+-------------------------+-------+--------------+-----------------+
| PRODUCT_ID |          ITEM           | PRICE | GROSS_MARGIN | Sum Of QUANTITY |
+------------+-------------------------+-------+--------------+-----------------+
| 100-10     | ALVE laptop table       |    89 | 56%          |           23323 |
| 100-15     | FREDRIK desk            |   129 | 44%          |            9614 |
| 100-20     | GALANT conference table |   369 | 32%          |           10272 |
+------------+-------------------------+-------+--------------+-----------------+
```

But I am unable to set up the query to do this as I am very new to access (really my first time toying around with it).

This is what my current query spits out:

```html
+------------+--------------------------+---------+--------------+--------------------+----------+
| PRODUCT_ID |           ITEM           |  PRICE  | GROSS_MARGIN | TRANSDATE By Month | QUANTITY |
+------------+--------------------------+---------+--------------+--------------------+----------+
| 100-10     | ALVE laptop table        | $89.00  | 56.00%       | August 2011        |     9679 |
| 100-10     | ALVE laptop table        | $89.00  | 56.00%       | July 2011          |     9436 |
| 100-10     | ALVE laptop table        | $89.00  | 56.00%       | June 2011          |     3222 |
| 100-10     | ALVE laptop table        | $89.00  | 56.00%       | May 2011           |      986 |
| 100-15     | FREDRIK desk             | $129.00 | 44.00%       | August 2011        |     3150 |
| 100-15     | FREDRIK desk             | $129.00 | 44.00%       | July 2011          |     2695 |
| 100-15     | FREDRIK desk             | $129.00 | 44.00%       | June 2011          |     3769 |
| 100-20     | GALANT conference table  | $369.00 | 32.00%       | August 2011        |     3814 |
| 100-20     | GALANT conference table  | $369.00 | 32.00%       | July 2011          |     4977 |
| 100-20     | GALANT conference table  | $369.00 | 32.00%       | June 2011          |      225 |
| 100-20     | GALANT conference table  | $369.00 | 32.00%       | May 2011           |     1256 |
+------------+--------------------------+---------+--------------+--------------------+----------+
```

Essentially, I want one row to sum up all sales for that item for those 4 months (May to August, inclusive of every day in the month). Ignore other columns (price & margin) if necessary.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I need to have this done by Friday!
Have been playing with it for hours but I seem to break something every time I get one step closer. :'(

Here is my current SQL syntax/code (sorry, unaware of the proper term).

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW 
     PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_ID, 
     PRODUCTS.ITEM, 
     PRODUCTS.PRICE, 
     PRODUCTS.GROSS_MARGIN,
     Format$([SALES].[TRANSDATE],'mmmm yyyy') AS [TRANSDATE By Month], 
     Sum(SALES.QUANTITY) AS [Sum Of QUANTITY]
FROM PRODUCTS INNER JOIN 
     SALES ON PRODUCTS.[PRODUCT_ID] = SALES.[PRODUCT_ID]
GROUP BY 
     PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_ID, 
     PRODUCTS.ITEM, 
     PRODUCTS.PRICE, 
     PRODUCTS.GROSS_MARGIN, 
     Format$([SALES].[TRANSDATE],'mmmm yyyy'), Year([SALES].[TRANSDATE])*12+DatePart('m',[SALES].[TRANSDATE])-1;
```

This actually currently shows all data for all months and years (I have 2 years worth of data for all products). I just want total sales for each product ID for the four months in one single year (May to August of 2011). PLEASE HELP!

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/71d47

Here is the fiddle with sample data for both tables.

Based on those tables, I want a query that brings in sales for each ID and totals them for the months of May to August in 2011 as outlined above. 

Any help is much appreciated.. spent over 4 days trying to figure this out... fresh eyes are needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this is Access, SQL Fiddle can only be a start.

You need to "quote" the date expressions correctly:

```
SELECT 
     PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_ID, 
     PRODUCTS.ITEM,      
     Sum(SALES.QUANTITY) AS [Sum Of QUANTITY]
FROM 
     PRODUCTS INNER JOIN 
     SALES ON PRODUCTS.[PRODUCT_ID] = SALES.[PRODUCT_ID]
WHERE 
    [SALES].[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN #2015-05-01# AND #2015-08-31#
GROUP BY 
     PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_ID, 
     PRODUCTS.ITEM
```

**Correction 2015-07-23**

I'm terribly sorry for missing that your original data had dates for 2011 and not 2011. I hereby post the corrected SQL for you to test:

```
SELECT 
     PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_ID, 
     PRODUCTS.ITEM,      
     Sum(SALES.QUANTITY) AS [Sum Of QUANTITY]
FROM 
     PRODUCTS INNER JOIN 
     SALES ON PRODUCTS.[PRODUCT_ID] = SALES.[PRODUCT_ID]
WHERE 
    [SALES].[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN #2011-05-01# AND #2011-08-31#
GROUP BY 
     PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_ID, 
     PRODUCTS.ITEM
```

This will produce an output from your Access database. For use with SQL Fiddler it will, however, be different:

```
SELECT 
     PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_ID, 
     PRODUCTS.ITEM,      
     Sum(SALES.QUANTITY) AS [Sum Of QUANTITY]
FROM 
     PRODUCTS INNER JOIN 
     SALES ON PRODUCTS.[PRODUCT_ID] = SALES.[PRODUCT_ID]
WHERE 
    [SALES].[TRANSDATE] BETWEEN '2011-05-01' AND '2011-08-31'
GROUP BY 
     PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_ID, 
     PRODUCTS.ITEM
```

Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I have tried this already and it returns no results the expected columns with no results. I am not sure where the query is getting bugged but this is what I felt was correct and it returned nothing.

I will upload parts of both tables to a fiddle later today, maybe that will help someone figure out the issue.

Comment: sqlfiddle.com/#!3/71d47 Here is the fiddle with sample data for both tables. Based on those tables, I want a query that brings in sales for each ID and totals them for the months of May to August in 2011 as outlined above. Any help is much appreciated.. spent over 4 days trying to figure this out... fresh eyes are needed. –

Comment: Such a query will return no records ... as you only have data between 2010-01 and 2011-03.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/db52cc updated to include months I mentioned (May - Aug 2011).